# Use Mammoth Library to convert Docx file to html in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, integration

I have requirement where i need to convert docx file data into html to make that editable in lwc component . For this use case I am using method 'convertToHtml' method from mammoth library . But getting the error .
The code i am using is below

```
handleFilesChange(blobData) {
   console.log('method called '+blobData);           
            if (window.mammoth) {
                console.log('Mammoth is accessible');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(window.mammoth));
            } else {
                console.error('Mammoth is not accessible');
            }
            window.mammoth.convertToHtml({blob: blobData})
                .then((result) => {
                    
                    console.log('html data =='+JSON.stringify(result.value));
                   // this.template.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = result.value;
                })
                .catch(err =>{console.log('4');
                console.log(err)});
       
}
```

I have already imported mammoth library as static resource

```
import MAMMOTH_JS from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/mammothJS";
```

Error message (Although that would not give any help that's why I did not add):
`Proxy(Object) {}`
Update:
I just consoled the window.mammoth and it generated :

```
{"images":{},"transforms":{},"underline":{}}
```

Did not understand the issue here ?

updated code ==>

```
convert(blob) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        console.log('convert==='+JSON.stringify(blob));
        try {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reader.onload = () => {resolve(
                
              // console.log('convert==='+JSON.stringify(blob));
               window.mammoth.convertToHtml({ arrayBuffer : reader.result })
               .then((result) => {
                   console.log('html data == ', result.value);
                   // this.template.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = result.value;
               })
               .catch(err =>{
                   console.error(err);
               }));
            }

           reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
           reader.onerror = (error) => reject(
            console.log('error ='+error)
           );
        });
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('catch error ='+JSON.stringify(err));
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please [edit] to add exact wording.

Comment: Lightning Locker or Lightning Web Security?

Comment: how to check those 
@FelixvanHove ?

Comment: Setup - Security - Session Settings - "Lightning Web Security".

Comment: @FelixvanHove hard luck, still getting the same results after disabled the "Lightning Web Security"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question in the comments (regarding the Lightning security you use) was a bit rash. The Mammoth lib works both with Locker and with LWS.

I'm not sure which Mammoth version you use, but I tested with 1.2.5. Scanning the front [page of the Github repo](https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js?tab=readme-ov-file#mammothconverttohtmlinput-options) doesn't surface a "blob" attribute of the object passed to the `convertToHtml` method. Here's a POC with the corrected attribute:

Javascript:

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import MAMMOTH_JS from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/mammothJS";

export default class MammothTest extends LightningElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        loadScript(this, MAMMOTH_JS)
        .catch(e => console.error('Mammoth not loaded: ', e));
      }

    handleFilesChange(event) {
        this.convert(event.detail.files[0]);
    }

    convert(blob) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            window.mammoth.convertToHtml({ arrayBuffer : reader.result })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('html data == ', result.value);
                // this.template.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = result.value;
            })
            .catch(e =>{
                console.error(e);
            });
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-input type="file" label="Select docx file..." onchange={handleFilesChange}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

Interestingly, fed with the wrong data, `convertToHtml` does not return. Fed with the right data however, it does what it's supposed to do. I saved a short text in Libre Office as "Word 2010-365 Document (*.docx)". Chrome's DevTools produced this:

`html data ==  <p>Hello <strong>NewBaySales</strong>!</p>`

Comment: Sorry i was little under the weather ,Anyways  I have made update to the code but looks like it is not executing the reader.onload = () call ,@FelixvanHove

Comment: Firstly, please don't update your original question in a way that the answer doesn't make much sense anymore. This isn't good for later readers. Secondly, what is the idea of the Promise that you added? Thirdly, - just copy the code I provided and you're done. It prints the `html data...` to the console. `reader.onload` is an event triggered by the execution of `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(...)`, which indicates `blob` has been read. This can hardly fail.

Comment: Copied and pasted the code that you provided but the reader is not executing .

Comment: @NewBaySales, I replaced my answer with a complete proof of concept - check it out! :-)

Comment: thank u very much @FelixvanHove , I was able to get the html code , Actually I think the issue was that I was using

  <lightning-file-upload ></lightning-file-upload>
this and getting the blob data from apex .

Comment: Although the formatting was not same as the docx file .